# Stucked on login user profile services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I have an image of a windows server 2012 in AWS. Sometimes when I try to initialize this machine I get stucked on the login screen with the message "Please wait for the user profile service". Then I completely lose the server. Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening and what I can do to avoid it?

Comment: Sounds like authentication. Using the right credentials?

Comment: Yes, it authenticates correctly but get stucked with this message.

Comment: Is this a brand new server ? or an existing one that has been configured previously ?

Comment: It's a server I configured with iis and .net 4.5 based on the windows server 2012 base that is provided by aws

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its related but I had a similar experience with Windows Server 2012 VMs hosted on Windows Server 2012. It was due to IPv6 being disabled on my setup.

Comment: Actually the problem was related to the sysprep. I was creating the image with it and was getting stucked in the login screen